# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n^4$ is convergent. Prove $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{+\infty} a_nn^{-\frac{4}{5}}$ is absolutely convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n^4$ is convergent. Prove $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{+\infty} a_nn^{-\frac{4}{5}}$ is absolutely convergent.

I find out the solution when $\{a_n^4\}$ is monotone decreasing. In this case, it is easy to prove that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}na_n^4 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{4}}|a_n| = 0$$
so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_n|n^{-\frac{4}{5}} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{|a_n|n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n^{\frac{21}{20}}}$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{21}{20}}}$ is convergent and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{1}{4}}|a_n| = 0$, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{|a_n|n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n^{\frac{21}{20}}}$$
is convergent.

And I also consider that the commutative law holds for absolutely convergent series so that we can turn this question into that when $\{a_n^4\}$ is monotone. Or I just need to prove that $\{|a_n|n^{\frac{1}{4}}\}$ is bounded without assuming that $\{a_n^4\}$ is monotone. But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) (with $p=4, q=\frac 43$) gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} | a_nn^{-\frac{4}{5}} | \le  \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n^4 \right)^{1/4} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} n^{-16/15}\right)^{3/4} 
$$
and the conclusion follows since both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^4 $ and
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-16/15}$ are convergent.